# Trying to solve an equation more efficiently

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I try to solve an equation. Normally, Mathematica code works but the problem is that it takes a huge amount of time.

The code I use is :

```
paramFinal2 = {ρ -> 0.05, γ -> 0.5, ω -> 0.8, ψ -> 15.5, α -> 0.3, β -> 0.06, λ -> 0.7, 
   Subscript[γ, 2] -> -0.6, Subscript[γ, 1] -> 0.9, η -> 4.25, χ -> 2, μ -> 0.1};
```

and

```
{power} = {1/(1 - α) (1 + Subscript[γ, 2]/Subscript[γ, 1] ) - 1 /. paramFinal2}
{power1} = {1 + Subscript[γ, 2]/Subscript[γ, 1]  η /. paramFinal2}
```

I have an integral to solve ;

```
solint[i_] := Integrate[(a^power/(1 + i/χ a^power1)^(α/(1 - α))), {a, 0, 1}] /. paramFinal2
```

The equation I try to solve is

```
msolres1[n_,i_] := (ρ + θ) + λ n - ((1 - n) (1 - ω) ψ θ)/(λ (1 - α)) - 
    (α Subscript[γ, 1])/(λ (1 - Subscript[γ, 1]) ) ((1 - n)/solint[i]) 
    ((χ + i)^(-(α/(1 - α)))/χ^(α/(1 - α)))
```

And finally, in order to have the results ;

```
solres1[i_] := NSolve[msolres1[n, i] /. paramFinal2, n] 
tabres1 = Table[solres1[i], {i, 0.01, 1.5, 0.1}] /. θ -> 0.01
solutionres1 = solres1[i];
```

How can I modify this code in a more efficient way to have results in a quicker way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you can calculate the integral and solutions to the equation  in your problem symbolically, so you don't need to compute them over and over numerically for every value of $i$.

Your assignments to `power` and `power2` seem to contain extraneous lists as well, which I removed below.

```
paramFinal2 = {ρ -> 5/100, γ -> 5/10, ω -> 8/10, ψ -> 155/10, α -> 3/10, β -> 6/100, 
    λ -> 7/10, Subscript[γ, 2] -> -6/10, Subscript[γ, 1] -> 9/10, η -> 425/100, 
    χ -> 2, μ -> 1/10};
power = (1/(1 - α) (1 + Subscript[γ, 2]/Subscript[γ, 1]) - 1) /. paramFinal2
power1 = (1 + Subscript[γ, 2]/Subscript[γ, 1] η) /. paramFinal2
```

The following are more substantial changes. Notice that the value of `solint` is assigned imemdiately, and not through `SetDelayed` (`:=`), so as to avoid recalculations.

```
solint[i_] = With[
   {integrand = (a^power/(1 + i/χ a^power1)^(α/(1 - α)) /. paramFinal2)},
   Integrate[integrand, {a, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> 0.01 <= i <= 1.5]
];
```

Without assumptions, `Integrate` would generate a conditional expression; this can be avoided by explicitly providing assumptions specifying that $i$ is real and non-zero.

```
msolres1[n_, i_] := (ρ + θ) + λ n - ((1 - n) (1 - ω) ψ θ)/(λ (1 - α)) -
   (α Subscript[γ, 1])/(λ (1 - Subscript[γ, 1])) ((1 - n) / solint[i]) *
   ((χ + i)^(-(α/(1 - α)))/χ^(α/(1 - α)))

solres1 = Solve[msolres1[n, i] == 0, n] /. paramFinal2 /. θ -> 0.01;
tabres1 = Table[solres1, {i, 0.01, 1.5, 0.1}]

(* Out:
{{{n -> 0.624808}}, {{n -> 0.672363}}, {{n -> 0.689797}}, {{n -> 0.700922}}, 
 {{n -> 0.709031}}, {{n -> 0.715345}}, {{n -> 0.720463}}, {{n -> 0.724729}}, 
 {{n -> 0.728358}}, {{n -> 0.731495}}, {{n -> 0.734239}}, {{n -> 0.736666}}, 
 {{n -> 0.73883}}, {{n -> 0.740774}}, {{n -> 0.742532}}}
*)
```

The calculation now only takes a few seconds.